# Eclipse & angularjs validation error: Unexpected token for import and export

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

I started to learn angular.js and build the hello world app according to the official angular site.

I'm working with *Spring Tool Suite 3.8.4* and installed the *AngularJS Eclipse 1.2.0* plugin and the test project was working fine without any validation errors.

After finishing this tutorial I made a git clone from [this demo application](https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4/blob/master/README.md), did all the installation steps, imported it as a project into Eclipse and configured it as an angular project (nature).

After all validation was done Eclipse showed me about 2500 errors with the message `Unexpected token`. I opened some files and it seems that the `import` and `export` keyword isn't recognized properly.

As the hello world app uses also these keywords and didn't have any validation errors I assume the reason could be a configuration problem. If i compare them in my project explorer i was wondering why in my hello world app was only a folder "TypeScript Resources (2.2.2)" and in this imported project there is also one folder/lib called "Javascript Resources". Might be ok, just something i noticed.

As im totally new to angular I have no clue what I could check. I read that the angular js support for the Eclipse IDE isn't perfect but these articles have been partly outdated as they were using Angular 1.x and 2.x.

Running the application with `npm start` in a terminal or "Run as" ==> ng serve" works fine without any problem.

Both applications (hello world and the cloned one) use Angular 4.x.
Does anybody have an idea? Do I need to provide more information?

[image: Screen]

Comment: It is because your eclipse wont support typescripts. you may need to install additional plugins. Search for type script and es-6 plugins in market place.

Comment: It's out of the scope of your issue, but I suggest you to install 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (soon released) which provides refactoring, completion, validation inside HTML Angular template. See https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/New-and-Noteworthy-1.3.0 and https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/New-and-Noteworthy-1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

At first just to clarify things, you have installed [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started) which is for `Angular2, Angular4` and where you develop with `TypeScript`. [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse) is for `Angular1` where you develop with `JavaScript`.

You error is a `JavaScript Problem` which comes from the `JSDT plugins`. It seems that you have added JSDT nature. I suggest you to remove JSDT nature from your project because you develop with TypeScript and not with JavaScript.

To do that you can edit your `.project` file and remove this line:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
```

If you need to open JavaScript file in an editor with validation, completion, etc, TypeScript IDE provide a JavaScript (Salsa) Editor which does that. You open your JS file with `JavaScript (Salsa) Editor`:

[image]

and after you benefit from the same feature than TypeScript editor:

[image]